# Cost of Reflection in moderns JVMs (6 onwards)

Tags: java, reflection

I want to know if the cost of reflection has gone down in modern JVMs that we can use it freely everywhere except the most critical sections in the code.

For example, if I want to invoke a method based on the method name given by a user as input. Now there are two ways to implemented this:

1. Use a if/else/switch to determine which method to call. This will obviously be a lot of code if there is a large number of cases.
2. Use reflection to invoke the method. This is definitely less code.

**Clarification**: Above is just an example where using reflection can shorten the amount of code. I just wanted to know if it is a valid strategy to replace a large amount of static code with some reflection magic. Also share any experiences if you have done something on the similar lines.

Comment: You could also use Strings in switch-cases in Java 7, we are doing this and have done away with a lot of if/else and even reflection calls.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's another way to do it that's better, in my opinion: use a Command pattern and a Map of name/command instance pairs.  You can scale that a very long way without switches or reflection.  It's polymorphic, too - far more "object oriented".

Take a look at the `java.lang.Runnable` or `java.util.concurrent.Callable` if you prefer to not use your own Command.  Your methods can be executed asynchronously if you wish.

It's not clear to me how users will specify which method they wish to invoke.  If you use reflection, they have to spell out the name of the class, the method, the parameters, and know the return type.  How do you intend to show them possible choices?  Every class, every method in your application?  Is anything fair game?

I think it's far more rational to present a list of choices that are prescribed in such a way that it's easy to specify and call.  I don't believe that any solution based on reflection meets that criterion.

You want to offer users a choice, but "anything goes" does not seem practical to me.

As for your concrete example offered below, which includes Spring Controllers and services, I would not use reflection.  If your users specify start or stop by passing an HTTP query parameter, better to map individual Controller methods to the specific URL that you have in mind using REST.  My preference is clarity, even if it's more verbose.

Comment: Interesting - I learn something new every day. Thank you for sharing @duffymo

Comment: But the Command patternn is quite a bit more verbose, requiring a whole class for each command. If the code for each command is typically just two-three lines, it's a lot of overhead.

Comment: Not really.  I think a Map is far less verbose and easier to extend than a long switch statement.  Your adjectives are subjective.  I say it's not a lot of overhead, and the cost is worth it.  It's certainly worth considering.

Comment: But the Map must be initialized. Compare Map initialization code with the switch statement.

Comment: Worth considering is all I'm saying.  Certainly not worth an argument.

Comment: An informed choice is based on all the relevant information. I am chipping in with my 2 cents.

Comment: Agreed.  My comment below is sarcasm intended to point out that chipping in with your bit can take a lot of forms.  Your argument has little basis.

Comment: (@MarkoTopolnik, what makes you say map initialization code is verbose?  Especially with e.g. Guava's `ImmutableMap` or builder syntax, I don't think it's very verbose at all, but I can see why you might say that it's verbose if you didn't have some library support.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman The map initialization code in question will have to deal with a separate class per map entry and that part is too verbose in Java for what it gives you. With Java 8 that's finally going to get a solution in the form of closures. Then there will be no more dispute: this approach combined with closures will be *The Right Way*.

Comment: Hrrrrrm.  I'm not convinced that that can't also be dealt with -- even today -- by a little library support; some kind of `Map` wrapper with a method `Handler<T> getHandler(Class<T> clazz)`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Aha, you mean reflection? Why yes, you can do it with reflection :) BTW I don't need Guava to have a quasi-map literal: `static <K,V> Map<K,V> hashMap(Object... kvs) {
    Map<K,V> m = new HashMap<K,V>();
    for (Iterator<?> it = asList(kvs).iterator(); it.hasNext();) m.put((K)it.next(), (V)it.next());
    return m;
  }`

Comment: I doubt that there will ever be a right way.  None of the alternatives presented here will lose their power under the right context.  If I call a Command pattern a context for execution, it starts to sound like a poor man's closure.

Comment: Okay, ignore everything I said before now.  If my understanding of the command pattern is correct, we just pass around callback objects instead of references to `Method`s.  I'm not sure, then, where the "map initialization code" is so painful.  Are we talking just something like `ImmutableMap.of("left", new LeftCommand(), "right", new RightCommand())`?  What's so bad about that?

Comment: duffymo Regarding your update, it wouldn't be a sane approach to make the client specify every detail of the method to call. You'll accept a name from the client and use it in your code that fetches the appropriate method, supplying everything else, and even perhaps transforming the `name` argument into the full name of the method.

Comment: @duffymo calling method by name was just an abstract example. A concrete example will be a spring controller where on the basis of PathVariables you want to invoke methods on a give service. So, instead of creating 2 methods in the controller for start/stop, I can do away with a single method that takes this action as a path variable and invoke the corresponding method. Generalizing further,  suppose that instead of one service object in the controller you have 10. Again, you can create separate handlers for them or use Pathvariable to identify which object to invoke the method on.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Now take into account the complete declaration of `LeftCommand`, `RightCommand` etc. and compare with the declaration of methods `left`, `right`. That's all the difference I have in mind.

Comment: Okay, I understand now.  I now concur with duffymo that that overhead is negligible compared to the ugliness of reflection.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, that's a sound position -- *de gustibus non est disputandum*. For me it's the other way around, but there is nothing to discuss about that.

Comment: You're really basing your whole argument on the keystroke difference between LeftCommand and left?  Please.  This is absurd.  Keystrokes are cheap.  Besides, you're writing Java.  It's verbose, by definition.  Get over it.

Comment: duffymo It is actually precisely because Java is so verbose that I have developed a collection of skills that will bring the verbosity down as much as possible. Reflection is one of my dear tools. The difference is between writing `new Command() { ... method declaration ...}` and writing **only** the method declaration. It still isn't a huge difference, but if your methods are short, it builds up. That's what I said at the outset. Of course, if you make every command a separate, named subtype of `Command`, then the difference really is substantial.

Comment: Sounds like you'd rather write Perl.  I don't consider the extra keystrokes to be a burden, not substantial at all.  I wonder if writing code is a team sport for you?  Conciseness can be good, but it can inhibit understanding by others if carried too far.  I wouldn't drive a design in a given direction just to save typing.  I'd rather see someone learn how to touch type.  We'll agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: Yes, I write code exclusively as a member of professional teams. Typing, of course, is a wicker man here. We're talking reading and maintaining code. I especially despise code that you have to scroll around like a madman to get a grip of. And it's true, once you use a terse language (Clojure in my case), you soon start holding that quality very dear to your heart. The cognitive---and emotional---difference is **huge**.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it has gone down, it is still magnitudes slower as compared to direct method calls / field accesses. But in your case, it really shouldn't matter since JVM is blazing fast these days. Do you see a *visible* performance impact to warrant such a question? Also, do realize that the colateral damage here is you lose all the static type-checking goodness.

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually true.  I used to think it was orders of magnitude slower, but these days the JIT is often smart enough to compile method invocations in directly; I've seen benchmarks that demonstrate less than an order of magnitude of difference.

Comment: I'm just worried about the performance. The static-type checking loss can be handled to some extent using unit tests.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: Bad choice of words I guess since magnitudes can stand for anything. My point was that reflection based code would never be faster than direct dispatch and it brings . I have written my share of reflection based code but I'd rather not go there unless absolutely necessary given that all bets are off on the type checking front.

Comment: @Anand Nalya: In that case take a look at the answer by duffymo; it can't get any faster than that if you are looking for a clean approach.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not recommending that the OP should use reflection -- indeed, I'd do almost anything to avoid using reflection myself.  (I strongly support duffymo's suggestion.) Honesty compelled me to admit that reflection is faster than it used to be -- I'll admit that I've seen at least one benchmark that got within 30% of the direct call -- but it's unmaintainable, verbose, and requires all sorts of ugly casts, and it's best avoided.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Just keep in mind that they are always testing only `Method.invoke` and not the whole procedure of first acquiring that method and then calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You must differentiate between two steps in a reflective method call: method lookup (slow) and method invocation (very fast). So all you really need to do is cache the `Method` instances and have a fast lookup solution for them. Then you'll have a win-win solution.

Comment: Where are you going to cache those Method instances?  In a Map?  Won't that be ridiculously expensive?

Comment: Why would a Map be expensive? It's certainly more expensive than a switch statement, and just as expensive as a Map of Commands. We're talking memory, I assume.

Comment: You seem to think it's very expensive above.  Why does it suddenly become so cheap and easy when you suggest it?  Methods take memory, too.  After all, they are objects, just as Commands are.

Comment: I didn't mention expensive. I said verbose. This is as expensive and less verbose.

Comment: Certainly, caching can be an issue if your objects have a short life, while if you have long living objects, say a singleton then this might be a viable approach.

Comment: But are you sure, that HashMaps are faster than method lookup? On what basis?

Comment: Anand, as for caching strategy the two proposals (command vs. method) are on equal footing. The issues will be the same. A Command is really a kludgy replacement for a lambda function, and in Java 8 the lamdas (closures, in fact) are coming to Java. When that happens, there will be no argument anymore: you'll use the lambdas in any situation of this kind and be happy.

Comment: @lechlukasz Not sure, just a hunch. A Method must be looked up based on much more than just its name, so caching by name is tantamount to reusing the results of processing. If it turns out that it is indeed as fast, then my proposal is even better: no caching, just straight method lookup every time. That would mean super-simple code which is at the same time killer-performant.